# Multiple sql joins from same reference table

Tags: mysql, sql

I currently have the following query:

```
select  title,location,categorie,division, 
    reference.description as CA 
from emploi 
left join reference on emploi.categorie = reference.code_ref 
where id_type = 'CA' and emploi.status ='1'
```

and I have a second query, which is the same but is taking a different value from the reference table:

```
select  title,location,categorie,division, 
    reference.description as DI 
from emploi 
left join reference on emploi.division = reference.code_ref 
where id_type = 'DI' and emploi.status ='1'
```

Is there a way to execute both these queries?

I was thinking it was something along the lines of the following, but it clearly does not work:

```
select  title,location,categorie,division, 
    reference.description as DI, reference.description as CA 
from emploi 
(left join reference on emploi.division = reference.code_ref 
    where id_type = 'DI')
(left join reference on emploi.categorie = reference.code_ref 
    where id_type = 'CA')
where emploi.status ='1'
```

Thank you!

**NOTE: Each entry from the emploi table has a division and categorie column, which need to both be mapped to separate entries ON THE SAME ROW**
EDIT:
This is the working solution, for those interested:

```
select  title,location,categorie,division, 
    r.description as DI, r1.description as CA 
from emploi 
left join reference r on emploi.division = r.code_ref 
    and r.id_type = 'DI'
left join reference r1 on emploi.categorie = r1.code_ref 
    and r1.id_type = 'CA'
where emploi.status ='1'
```

Comment: WHERE id_type IN('DI','CA') ??? And to which table do each of those columns belong (title,location,categorie,division,id_type)

Comment: @Strawberry i can't use IN because I want to link both the entry with the id_type of CA and the id_type of DI to the same entry. title,location,categorie,division are all apart of emploi, where id_type is part of reference.

Comment: @user3397607:- Then you can use the `and` condition instead of `where` like `left join reference on emploi.division = reference.code_ref and id_type = 'DI'`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may try this:

```
select  title,location,categorie,division, 
    r.description as DI, r1.description as CA 
from emploi 
left join reference r on emploi.division = r.code_ref 
left join reference r1 on emploi.categorie = r1.code_ref 
where emploi.status ='1'
and id_type in ('CA', 'DI')
```

Presently you are having an incorrect syntax as you are using the `where` clause two times with your `left join`. Also put the alias to your tables and use those alias to get the column name

Something like

```
select  tablename.title,tablename.location,tablename.categorie,tablename.division, 
    r.description as DI, r1.description as CA 
from emploi 
left join reference r on emploi.division = r.code_ref 
left join reference r1 on emploi.categorie = r1.code_ref 
where emploi.status ='1'
and id_type in ('CA', 'DI')
```

**Note:** Use the correct table name in place of `tablename` above

**EDIT:-**

If you dont want to use the IN clause then

```
select  title,location,categorie,division, 
    r.description as DI, r1.description as CA 
from emploi 
left join reference r on emploi.division = r.code_ref 
    and r.id_type = 'DI'
left join reference r1 on emploi.categorie = r1.code_ref 
    and r1.id_type = 'CA'
where emploi.status ='1'
```

Assuming that `id_type` is a column of `emploi`

Comment: I get an error saying that: Tables or functions 'reference' and 'reference' have the same exposed names. Use correlation names to distinguish them.

Comment: @user3397607:- Updated. Please check

Comment: I made a few modifications, but this works perfectly! Thank you! `select  title,location,categorie,division, 
    r.description as DI, r1.description as CA 
from emploi 
left join reference r on emploi.division = r.code_ref 
    and r.id_type = 'DI'
left join reference r1 on emploi.categorie = r1.code_ref 
    and r1.id_type = 'CA'
where emploi.status ='1'`

Comment: @user3397607:- You are welcome. Glad to help. Happy coding :) Was not aware of the table design ;)

Answer (score 1):

There are a couple of ways of achieving this:

```
select  title,location,categorie,division, 
reference.description as DI 
from emploi 
left join reference on emploi.division = reference.code_ref 
where id_type IN ('DI','CA') and emploi.status ='1'
```

or you can change the where clause to an OR

```
where (id_type = 'DI' OR id_type = 'CA') and emploi.status ='1'
```

or if you are looking forward to what you wrote originally then

```
select  title,location,categorie,division, 
reference.description as DI, reference.description as CA 
from emploi 
left join reference r1 on emploi.division = r1.code_ref 
and r1.id_type = 'DI'
left join reference r2 on emploi.categorie = r2.code_ref 
and r2.id_type = 'CA'
```

Or a couple of other ways also...

Comment: This is really close, but this causes duplicates instead of combining them into the same row.

Answer (score 0):

it should work without the brackets ( ), aliasing the tables and prefixing the fields with alias.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post - you can always comment on your own posts, and once you have sufficient [reputation](http://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](http://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment).

Comment: thanks for the advice. As you guessed I hadn't enough reputation to comment on the question.

Answer (score 0):

```
select  title,location,categorie,division, 
    reference.description as CA 
from emploi 
left join reference  reference on emploi.categorie = reference.code_ref 
left join reference reference1 on emploi.division = reference1.code_ref
where id_type in('CA','DI') and emploi.status ='1' order by id_type
```

this will work for you , here order by is used to define the order of select statement

Comment: It is telling me i need to use correlation names `Tables or functions 'reference' and 'reference' have the same exposed names. Use correlation names to distinguish them.
`